# Overriding Material UI Badge style is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to translate and position the `Badge` component by overriding the root CSS style, but for some reason it's not taking anything into effect. My `Card` component seems to be seeing the styling via the `className` prop, but I for some reason I the `Badge` component isn't seeing anything. I am following the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/badge).

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import { Badge } from "@material-ui/core";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    anchorOriginTopRightRectangle: {
      transform: "translate(-100%, -50%)"
    }
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
}));

const CardItem = ({
  name,
  discount
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader
        title={
            <>
                {name}
                <Badge
                badgeContent={`-10%`}
                color="error"
                ></Badge>
            </>
        }
        subheader={"$1234"}
      />
        // ... Card content
    </Card>
  );
};

export default(CardItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import { Badge } from "@material-ui/core";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  anchorTopRight: {
      transform: "translate(-100%, -50%)"
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
}));

const CardItem = ({
  name,
  discount
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader
        title={
            <>
                {name}
                <Badge
                classes={{ anchorOriginTopRightRectangle: classes.anchorTopRight}} // <== Working Code
                badgeContent={`-10%`}
                color="error"
                ></Badge>
            </>
        }
        subheader={"$1234"}
      />
        // ... Card content
    </Card>
  );
};

export default(CardItem);
```